# Как заменить класс объекта из v-for VUE3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Есть выпадающий список, хочу сделать так, что-бы при клике на элемент у него обновлялся класс на другой, но обновляются сразу все элементы, как привязать класс именно к тому элементу на которой кликнули?

```
<p @click="choiceOption" class="optionText" :class="{ active: isActive }" v-for="option in options" :key="option.value"> 

{{ option.text }}
</p>

methods:{
     choiceOption(option){
         this.textSelecteds = option.srcElement.innerText;
         this.$emit('update', option);
         this.isVisible = false;
         this.isActive = true;
       }
}
```

Comment: 1. Запихнуть ваш `p` в отдельный компонент. И `v-for`ить этот компонент уже.

Comment: Все равно при нажатии стили применяются ко всем компонентам, подскажите, что не так.`<TestComponent @click="choiceOption" class="optionText" :class="{ active: isActive }" v-for="option in options" :option="option" :key="option.value"/> ` 
  `<template>
    <p> 
        {{ option.text }}
      </p>
</template>

export default {
    props: {
        option: {
            type: Object
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Я новичок во vue, и хотелось бы узнать это нормальная практика для таких целей и задач? Создавать отдельный компонент для компонента...

Comment: Дак внутри компонента клик отслеживай и классы делай

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно вот так:

```
<template>
<div>
  <p 
    v-for="(option, index) of options" 
    :key="index" 
    :option="option" 
    :class="{ 'active-class': selectedOption === option.id }" 
    @click="makeActive({ id: option.id })"
  >
    {{option.value}}
  </p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      options: [
        { id: 1, value: 'one' },
        { id: 2,value: 'two' },
        { id: 3,value: 'three' }
      ],
      selectedOption: null // Важно
    }
  },
  methods: {
    makeActive ({ id }) {
      this.selectedOption = id
    }
  }
}
</script>
```